# Use camel getOriginalMessage() in spring/blueprint DSL Route

Tags: apache-camel, dsl, blueprint-osgi

```
<setBody>
    <simple>**exchange.getUnitOfWork().getOriginalInMessage()**</simple>
</setBody>
```

Using Spring/blueprint DSL, how can i setBody with the original message in a camel route?

Answer (score 0):

Use an inline processor:

```
.process(new Processor() {
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        exchange.setIn(exchange.getUnitOfWork().getOriginalInMessage());                    
    }
});
```

Comment: I can't seem to find the syntax to do the same in Spring DSL

Comment: If this solves your issue, please upvote me and select my answer.